# Tika with Grobid throwing error when parsing pdf document

Tags: tika-server, grobid

I am trying to extract both document metadata and journal header metadata from a pdf document. I verified that Tika Server (v1.21 / v1.24) and Grobid (v0.6.0) are independently able to extract metadata from the pdf document. However, when I run Grobid within Tika Server ( following instructions mentioned in  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/GrobidJournalParser ), I get the below error (snippet) for the same pdf document:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
        at org.apache.tika.utils.XMLReaderUtils.buildDOM(XMLReaderUtils.java:407)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.journal.TEIDOMParser.parse(TEIDOMParser.java:44)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.journal.GrobidRESTParser.parse(GrobidRESTParser.java:85)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.journal.JournalParser.parse(JournalParser.java:60)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.ParserDecorator.parse(ParserDecorator.java:188)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.ParserDecorator.parse(ParserDecorator.java:188)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.RecursiveParserWrapper.parse(RecursiveParserWrapper.java:224)
        at org.apache.tika.server.resource.TikaResource.parse(TikaResource.java:422)
    ....
```

I ran the below command to start Tika Server with Grobid:

```
java -classpath /home/avlurs/grobid-0.6.0/grobidparser-resources/:tika-server-1.21.jar org
.apache.tika.server.TikaServerCli --config /home/avlurs/grobid-0.6.0/grobidparser-resources/tika-config.xml &
```

I ran the below command to test the metadata extraction:

```
curl -T /home/avlurs/temp/in/JournalTest.pdf -H "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=
JournalTest.pdf" http://localhost:9998/rmeta
```

In addition to throwing the above mentioned error, I am getting the document metadata from Tika in the output. However, Grobid metadata is not being extracted.

Appreciate any inputs / suggestions to address this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Grobid service updated the location of their API endpoints to under /api in July 2017 but the GrobidParser wasn't updated to use the new location.

I've just committed a fix for this as part of [TIKA-3191](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3191), which will be released in Tika 1.25. We're hoping to get that out in the next few week, but until then you can use a source build or a snapshot build.

I also plan to update the Tika [GrobidParser Wiki Page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/GrobidJournalParser) to have more up to date instructions in place that explain using the current Gradle build and Docker image options Grobid has these days.

Comment: Apache Tika 1.25 has been released now with the fix included. I've also created a docker-compose based example [here](https://github.com/apache/tika-docker/blob/master/docker-compose-tika-grobid.yml) for anyone looking to try it out.